# Extract values from column under given conditions of other column

Tags: r

I have the following given:

```
TR  Avg RE
3   0
3   0
4   209.3524872
3   185.6542898
3   0
3   0
3   0
4   136.7522375
4   157.6887675
4   0
3   202.8994858
3   0
3   89.45242983
4   0
3   0
3   218.4987273
3   192.4212849
```

I want to extract only those values of RE where TR is equal to 4 - how can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You already have the answer from David's comment. However, for interest below is few additional methods to do it.

***Code:***

```
# Method 1:
df[df$TR == 4, "RE"]

# Method 2:
df[ which(df$TR == 4), "RE"]

# Method 3:
subset(df$RE, df$TR == 4)

# Method 4: You could also use the sqldf package to use sql
# install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select RE from df where TR = 4')
```

Comment: What do I do if I have two conditions TR and QED? I tried subset(df$RE, df$TR == 1, df$QED == 1). Sorry if it sounds lazy..I searched but found nothing so far

Comment: Use `&` operator i.e., `subset (df$RE, df$TR ==1 &  df$QED ==1)`